# Tor socks libtorsocks warning

Tags: torsocks, terminal

I using the torsocks with curl.

```
torsocks curl icanhazip.com
```

It shows the following error

> ```
> libtorsocks(15700): WARNING: The symbol res_querydomain() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
>   Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_querydomain() with the reported error: Not Found
> ```

How to i solve it